# Windows Remote Target System With Nsight Eclipse Edition 10. Is it possible?

Tags: cuda, nsight

I have a Mac with an unsupported GPU...but I also have a Windows 10 machine running SSH that does have a supported GPU (and fully setup to run CUDA).

I'm trying to set up the remote target system on my Mac within Nsight Eclipse Edition. I can add the remote connection to the Windows machine without issue, but when I try to configure the toolkit for the remote connection I run into problems.

I can enter (or browse on the remote Windows computer) the path to the Toolkit binaries. No matter what I enter, it will always says something like  `'/C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.2/bin/nvprof' does not exist'`.

If I click on the 'Detect...' button, it will try to detect available toolkits, but will then pop an error dialog saying "Unable to execute shell commands. Failed to execute "bash -i which nvcc". Obviously that won't work on Windows.

What this is telling me is that a Windows machine cannot be used as a remote target. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What this is telling me is that a Windows machine cannot be used as a remote target. Is this correct?

yes, that is correct.

Referring to the Nsight EE Documentation:

[Section 3.6](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-development) indicates that for development, the remote system must be linux.

> The remote target system can be a Linux x86 or POWER system with an NVIDIA GPU or an Tegra-based ARM system.

[Section 3.7](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-debugging) indicates that for debugging, the remote (target) must be linux.

> Only Linux targets are supported.